# Selenium for Chrome version 103 is just crashing, I know it's not my code because whilst its still crashing at one time it still ran

Tags: selenium-webdriver-python

The script is crashing on Chrome version 103 only it's still running on 102. In one instance, it ran but crashed while executing a loop for its fifth time. It is selenium + python. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

this issue came with chrome 103. Remove the user-data-dir option for solution.

It was fixed for me when I removed the user-data-dir option.

It looks like this problem will go away when chrome 104 is released, we'll be dealing with workarounds until chrome 104 comes out.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=4121

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10799

Comment: the user-data-dir option fixes it for around 4 concurrent runs and then starts crashing again.

In some options, user-data-dir is very important as it reduces script interruption because it shows the user was there. Without the user-data-dir option, it's like opening a new browser each time you run the script.

Comment: this is a temporary solution, i am waiting for chrome 104 version to fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

## New Answer

Chrome Version 103.0.5060.134, selenium is now working as normal

## Old answer

I actually:

1. Uninstalled Google Chrome
2. Restarted the computer
3. Installed an older version of Chrome(whilst the Internet is OFF)
4. Run MS config & disable Chrome auto-update
5. Restart the computer.

Now it runs just FINE.

**NB: This can make your computer vulnerable to attacks so don't use your main PC. Use Isolated Environments**

.